# PHP mysql require assistance handling a var with and without a set value

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
$read2 = "SELECT * FROM `elmtree_transactions` WHERE sellerid ='$sellerid'";
if ($result2 = $conn->query($read2)) {
    while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rating = $row2['rating'];
    }
}
echo "                  
    <div class='col-sm-3 pt-3'>
    <div class='card'>
    <div class='card-header'>
        <strong>$user</strong><br>
        Seller Rating : $rating / 5 <img src='/elmtree/images/star.png' class=' img-rating' />
        </div>
    ";
```

Set up a seller rating. If the seller has a rating in the MySQL table it displays it on the page. If they don't it throws an error cause the `$rating` var to be undefined, which causes the webpage to look broken. Would like to be bale to manage this and show 0/5 or "seller has no rating yet" when no rating is in the MySQL table

Comment: Did u try to declare $rating =0; before $read2?. your code seem to be missing a default value for $ratng. Beside that, you can also do this on echo ($rating==""?0:$rating)

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection) in it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `mysql` query while will only loop through if there is a value returned from `mysql`

In OP there isn't really a accurate defenition of the error your getting. But I am assuming now that your experiencing a warning error about the variable not already initialized.

So, By good practice i would init the variable `$rating` before that loop like so

```
$rating = null;
$read2 = "SELECT * FROM `elmtree_transactions` WHERE sellerid ='$sellerid'";
if ($result2 = $conn->query($read2)) {
    while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rating = $row2['rating'];
    }
}
echo "                  
    <div class='col-sm-3 pt-3'>
    <div class='card'>
    <div class='card-header'>
        <strong>$user</strong><br>
        ".(is_numeric($rating)?"Seller Rating : $rating / 5 <img src='/elmtree/images/star.png' class=' img-rating' />":'No rating available yet')."
        </div>
    ";
```

Comment: what is `underfined` string coming from and why?

Comment: just assuming like said in my reply, based on the OP saying his output is undefined.

Comment: $read2 = "SELECT * FROM `elmtree_transactions` WHERE sellerid ='$sellerid'";
   if ($result2 = $conn ->query($read2)){
    while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
     $rating = $row2['rating'];   
    }
   }
     if($rating == 'undefined'){
      echo "<div class='col-sm-3 pt-3'>
      <div class='card'>
      <div class='card-header'>
       <strong>$user</strong><br>
       Seller Rating : Seller has no rating yet<img src='/elmtree/images/star.png' class=' img-rating' />
       </div>";
      }else{
      echo etc etc ect
@NicolasRacine I did that but its throwing an error

Comment: This answer has [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection) in it.

Comment: @Lux see my updated anwser.
Also Chipster is right. You have the posibility of having SQL injection if the value $sellerid is in any way interactable with user data i would setup my mysql request properly.

Comment: @Chipster this should be a coment for the OP, not the anwser ;)  I aint going to change the code not asked for.

Comment: @NicolasRacine That worked perfectly, youre a star, thank you so much!!